# Check if table is empty in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

```
IF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM IPA_PRCADJ_HDR WHERE TRM_CODE = 41) = 0)
THEN
  select '111111' from dual;
ELSE
 SELECT '0000000' FROM DUAL;
END IF;
```

showing error..

Error starting at line 73 in command:

```
END IF
ERROR REPORT:
Unknown Command
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't build conditions like this. Try to build them inside the `select` statement like this:

```
select case
       when exists
            ( select 1
              from   IPA_PRCADJ_HDR
              where  TRM_CODE = 41
            )
       then '111111'
       else '0000000'
       end
from   dual
```

Comment: The query was incorrect as the "select 1 from..." statement yielded no results when the table was empty.

Answer (score 0):

This takes into account the scenario when the table is empty.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN MAX(TRM_CODE) IS NULL THEN 'FALSE' ELSE 'TRUE' END FROM (SELECT * FROM IPA_PRCADJ_HDR WHERE TRM_CODE = 41)
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try this:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM IPA_PRCADJ_HDR)
 SELECT '111111' FROM DUAL;
ELSE
 SELECT '0000000' FROM DUAL;
```